# SQL - Selecting Records with an odd number of a given attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, modulus

I'm just brushing up on some SQL - in other words, I'm *really* rusty - and am a bit stuck at the moment. It's probably something trivial, but we'll see.

I'd like to select all people that possess an odd number of a certain attribute that isn't an integer ( in this example, TransactionType). So, for example, take the following test/not real info where these people are buying a car or some similarly big purchase.

```
Name TransactionType Date

John   Buy           5/1
John   Cancel        5/1
John   Buy           5/2
Joseph Buy           5/25
Joseph Cancel        5/25
Tanya  Buy           5/28
```

I would like it to return the people who had an odd number of transactions; in other words, they ended up purchasing the item. So, in this case, John and Tanya would be selected and Joseph would not.

I know I can use the modulus operand here, but I'm a bit lost how to utilize it correctly.
I thought of using

```
count(TransactionType) % 2 != 0
```

in the where clause but that's obviously a no-go. Any pointers in the right direction would be very helpful. Let me know if this is unclear, and thanks!

Comment: is that all of the columns you have? does your date column have a time included?

Comment: No, this is not my actual data. But, to be accurate to what I have, I have a sales_date - that is stored as a varchar for some reason -_-

Comment: does that include the time?

Comment: No it does not - it looks like: 12-MAY-14, for example.

Comment: does it have an incrementing id or something so you have any idea of which item was added first? you would need something like this to adopt my approach.

Comment: There are two columns that could be useful then: ID (which is the primary key) and insertion_date (which refers to the datetime at which the given record was inserted into a text file).

Comment: My solution should work if you swap the date field for the other date or the Id, as it will return the latest record based on the highest ID /date per buyer where the transaction type = Buy

Comment: What you've provided is very helpful. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you be better off getting the latest status by the transaction date and using that rather than relying on counting `TransactionType` to determine the latest status:

Something like this:

```
SELECT b.Name, b.TransactionType, b.[Date]
FROM (
   SELECT Name, MAX(t1.[DATE]) latestDate
   FROM [Transactions] t1
   GROUP BY t1.Name
   ) a
INNER JOIN [Transactions] b ON b.Name = a.Name AND a.latestDate = b.[Date]
WHERE b.TransactionType = 'Buy'
```

Assuming your dates are valid dates with times included, this should work.

### [Sample SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26c9f/1)

If you only store the date portion the max date would be the same for people that *Buy* and *Cancel* on the same date, therefore it would return more data and some incorrect records.

Answer (score 3):

You are close.  You need a having clause instead of a where clause.

```
select Name
from table
group by Name
having count(TransactionType) % 2 != 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Knew I was missing something relatively obvious :)